Nano on Windows: white-on-white help text
I am using nano for Windows in the terminal application on Windows 11. I have my terminal set to black text on a white background. (There are reasons for this, please don't suggest WSL or mingw.)
By default, nano displays file contents as white-on-white, so I edit the config file to contain:
syntax "all" ".*"
color black "^.*$"

(I'm not fussed about syntax highlighting.)
However, the help text from ^G is still white-on-white, as is the file contents when I turn syntax of with M-Y.
How can I tell nano "the default is black text, not white, everywhere". I think this is a generic .nanorc question, unless on windows it's not picking up some termcap correctly. But there might still be a config file option?
The default provided nanorc gives me a lot of options with comments and explanations, but I can't seem to find the one I need. rawsequences doesn't fix the problem.
This is nano version v7.2-22.1 2023.04.15. The older nano 2.2.6 (compiled 07:19:34, Nov 22 2010) actually gets this right: it doesn't seem to do color at all, but does display text black on white, not white on white.
